# How to differentiate trigger update versus manual user update

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger that updates a lead field: Rate_Total__c. I also need the ability for all users in the organization to overwrite the Rate_Total field. But because the trigger's main purpose is to update the value in Rate_Total__c, the trigger keeps firing, and overwriting user-input.

My question is: How can I write my trigger, so that it can differentiate a trigger-generated field update, versus a user-generated update?

Comment: well worth reading Enterprise Design Patterns - Separation of Concerns: http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/11/16/apex-enterprise-patterns-separation-of-concerns/ -- trigger logic exists at the database layer and as such should be insensitive to context; that said, restructuring existing code to this pattern can be 'work' given an existing code base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you create a checkbox field on the lead record that is call Override_Rate_Total.   Let your users know that they will have to check that box to make sure the override will stick.  If you are concerned that they will not remember to check this box, then you can create a button on the record called "Override Rate Total".  When they click the button, add some javascript ask for the rate total.  Then the javascript can update the Override_Rate_Total to be true and update the Rate_Total__c

Then add a check in your trigger to see if Override_Rate_Total == true.  If it is true, then abort the trigger.

Comment: Yea, that seems like the best work-around. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ALL triggers are invoked by **USERS** as everything done in Salesforce requires authentication and is run in the context of the authenticated user.......

What you will need to do is develop a system that indicates which code should not be run if it is in a specified user context...

This in itself creates problems as it is an ALL or Nothing for that user.

If you know specific code should NOT cause a trigger for example to execute then you should set a falg that the trigger checks to "opt out" for example.

You are going to have to identify all pathways in which the trigger can be invoked and decide which approach is best for you entire org...